# A metaphor for "ricochet back"

Tags: metaphors

Is there a metaphor or a single word for "When you throw a rubber ball into a wall and it bounces back and hits you." Something like boomerang, but unexpected and with negative connotation.

Comment: You mean it also in a figurative sense, like  bad actions whose effects may affect you negatively?

Comment: Josh61, Correct.

Comment: 'Boomerang' (the verb) _has_ a slight negative connotation, and it always surprised me when my toy one came back.

Comment: In addition to what @Edwin says, a rubber ball bouncing off a wall is not unexpected in my book. A boomerang coming back is actually way *more* unexpected, because you have to throw it correctly for that, while a rubber ball will bounce no matter what.

Comment: Despite what @EdwinAshworth said, I've _always_ heard "boomerang" used in a _very_ negative sense, of unexpected consequences. Note that outside of English-speaking countries, what a boomerang is and how it behaves may not be well known.

Comment: Rebound is another similar word with somewhat less negative consequences.

Comment: @Phil Perry The highly metaphorical sense (= backfire) is certainly used with a sense of causing unexpected harm to the instigator. But OP is hardly asking for the highly metaphorical sense (no projectiles involved) here. The negative denotation of the 'backfire' sense informs the physical return sense, giving a slight negative connotation there. // Note that this is a website discussing English, so whether or not 'boomerang' is a known term in non-English-speaking countries is hardly relevant here.

Comment: I would have said that English use of "ricochet", unless you're speaking of bullets or other weaponry projectiles, usually *was* a metaphor.

Comment: Note that "ricochet back" is close to a tautology.

Answer (score 20):

Consider [**backfire**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backfire), [**backlash**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backlash), [**kickback**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kickback), and [**payback**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/payback).

> backfire: a miscalculation that recoils on its maker
>
> backlash: a strong negative reaction, as to some social or political change
>
> kickback: a sharp violent reaction
>
> payback: a bad or unpleasant thing that someone does to you after you've done something bad or unpleasant to them. E.g. payback on French Nazi [collaborators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_of_Nazi_collaborators) after WW2.

Comment: Would definitely use backfire.

Answer (score 10):

One word that could work is *blowback.*

Definition of BLOWBACK

:  an unforeseen and unwanted effect, result, or set of repercussions

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blowback

Answer (score 6):

> When Geoffrey slandered his ex's new boyfriend on Facebook, the equally negative remarks from his ex's friends [**came back to bite him**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+back+to+bite+you).

Answer (score 3):

> Hoist with his own petard

... is —[as far as I can see](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=petard)— a Shakespearian phrase for a plan going so wrong that it is inflicted back on the perpetrator. Literally to be blown up/over/away by a small bomb used for breaching that you set.

It does really only work within the context of a plan or some other pre-meditated plan. An accident doesn't quite cater to this enough. It really benefits from showing some malevolence and forethought:

> Desperate to knock the cawing crow down from his fence, Albert picked up a stone and took careful aim. He took a second to imagine of the lie-in he would enjoy the next morning, devoid of this twittering bag of feathers. Time slowed as Albert unfurled. Seeing the shot leave his hand, he would have bet his grandma on hitting the bird but as he was carried around by the momentum of such a colossal throw, the flight-path drooped. The stone hit the fence and, hoisting Albert upon his own petard, cracked him in the side of the head.

Answer (score 2):

[to recoil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recoil) may suggest the meaning you describe:

> to jerk back, as from an impact or violent thrust.

In a figurative sense I'd say [karmic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Karmic):

> of an action seen as bringing upon oneself inevitable results, either in this life or in a reincarnation.

Answer (score 1):

"Karma" might work in a metaphorical sense. Such as the act of throwing something or doing wrong causes bad things to happen to you. This may be a far stretch though!

Answer (score 0):

"What goes around, comes around."

Popular idiom that captures this notion.

Answer (score 0):

"Rebound" is a single word with this kind of meaning.

Comment: I agree - it _can_ have a negative flavour, when used metaphorically.